# Creating a box with a arrow CSS3 Issue

Tags: css, shapes, css-shapes

I am trying to create an arrow `10px by 10px` on the right hand side of my bubble but I cannot see it.  So far I have:

**CSS:**

```
.pageHelp{
    float:right;
    margin:10px 20px 0 0;
    width:85px;
    height:25px;
    background-color:#354E69;
    border-radius:3px;
}
.pageHelp:before{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    right:100%;
    top:26px;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-top:13px solid transparent;
    border-right:26px solid #354E69;
    border-top:13px solid transparent;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="pageHelp"><p>In Page Help</p></div>
```

**Luis:**

```
.pageHelp{
    float:right;
    margin:10px 20px 0 0;
    width:85px;
    height:25px;
    background-color:#354E69;
    border-radius:3px;
    position: relative;
}
.pageHelp:after, .pageHelp:before {
    left: 100%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.pageHelp:after {
    border-left-color: #354E69;
    border-width: 10px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -10px;
}
.pageHelp:before {
    border-left-color: ##354E69;
    border-width: 16px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -16px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using this friendly [css-arrow-maker-help](http://cssarrowplease.com/)

Comment: Thanks Luis thats amazing.  I have updated my question CSS I asked for a 10px arrow but in my code I get http://d.pr/i/LyId

Comment: Does [this](http://jsfiddle.net/luissanchezm86/DKXJx/) works? it's 10px `height` and `width`, just adjust the padding to your needs!

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify

```
position: relative;
```

On your `.pageHelp` class; otherwise, the `position: absolute` on the `:before` content doesn't refer to it.

You also have `border-top` specified twice; I presume that one of those should be `border-bottom`.

If you fix those two, then you should at least be able to see the triangle next to the div.

Working mockup here: http://jsfiddle.net/Nzazm/

Comment: Thanks,  I have adjusted it so that it is 5px 10px 5px but how could I align it center?  There also seems to be a white gap

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help: http://jsfiddle.net/EkaMc/

The first thing is adding `position:relative` to `.pageHelp`

```
.pageHelp{
    [...]
    position:relative;
}
```

This will help position your arrow *relatively* to your bubble.

Then for your pseudo-element, I suggest you start by using `content:" "`. I've had bad luck trying to style pseudo-elements without any content, and I'm not exactly sure why. Maybe a more experienced user can help clarify.

```
.pageHelp:before{
    [...]
    content:" ";
}
```

Styling your arrow `right:100%` will bump it to the left extremity of your bubble. Plus, if you don't set `position:relative;`, your arrow will be forced out of the page.

```
.pageHelp:before{
    content:" ";
    position:absolute;
    right:-23px;
    top:6px;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-top:7px solid transparent;
    border-left:13px solid #354E69;
    border-bottom:7px solid transparent;
    border-right:13px solid transparent;
}​
```

You can play around the border sizes and see what works for you.

Comment: Thanks, I have adjusted it so that it is 5px 10px 5px but how could I align it center? There also seems to be a white gap